# Copy text in emacs and jump back to original position to paste

Tags: emacs

I'm at a place in a file and can mark the location. I search to a new location to copy a bit of text. Now I want to go back to the original location to paste it in. However, exchange point and mark won't help me here since I've used them to copy the text.

Any ideas on how I can somehow mark the original location and get back to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd> to pop off a mark from the mark-ring and jump to it.

Comment: Also it's recommended to set `(setq set-mark-command-repeat-pop t)`, so you can keep pressing C-SPC to go back multiple positions without also having to press C-u again.